# How to handle individual Datarepeater Item Events in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, controls, items, datarepeater

Using Visual Basic 2010 Express

See link below for a screenshot of my form.

The left 2/3, in alternating blue & gray backgrounds, is a datarepeater.
How can i access/handle events of the individual repeater item controls? For instance, one thing i want to do is write code that will be triggered when a user clicks on or even hovers over the box that says "Info" (called out in my screenshot as 'picturebox1') on each item.

Additionally, if this wasn't clear, i need to refer somehow to the repeater item in which the control was clicked. ie. my code needs to know that the "Info" button was clicked in the part number 0053766 item, not just that an "Info" button was clicked in general.

[Screenshot of my form](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9P1d3TwZYYfdFhpN0dnbGJzVW8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I just had the same question. But I see no one has answered you in almost 4 years. :-(